# Understanding splits in xgboost

Tags: python, classification, decision-tree, xgboost

I must be missing something simple in my understanding of the splits in the underlying trees when using xgboost.

If I use  model.tree_to_dataframe(), I have been mentally interpreting the number given for the Split column as, "If the value is greater than X, then Yes, else No". So, when all the splits for dummy features are set to 1, I took that to mean that a 1 followed the Yes split, and a 0 followed the No split.

However, when I actually plot the trees, I see this:

[image: Single Node Tree]

where the feature shown is a dummy variable. Since it says that current_X < 1, that obviously means that 0 should be yes and 1 should be no. Beyond being a bit unintuitive, it also doesn't make sense in the context of this data.

This dummy feature is highly predictive of the class. I chose this specifically because I knew it was highly predictive. But, if I transform the leaf values using 1/(1+exp(leaf)), the "yes" split returns a much higher probability than the no. (And I know you can't really base things off of one tree, but if I sum all leaf values for this variable, I get the same relationship.)

So, based on my knowledge of the data, it would make more sense for the yes split to represent a 1 and no to represent 0 (which, again, also seems more intuitive to me).

So, am I:

- Misinterpreting the tree diagram;
- Misinterpreting the dataframe output; or,
- Miscalculating the leaf value transformation?

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question here. I'm missing a sign in the inverse logit transformation ([source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395697/what-is-an-intuitive-interpretation-of-the-leaf-values-in-xgboost-base-learners))

I should be applying 1/(1+exp(***-***leaf)), which corrects the issue.